# Remove two largest unique numbers from a vector

Tags: r

I have `x` as

```
x <- c("7", "2", "3", "8", "8")
```

I want output

```
[1] "2" "3" "8"
```

and remove one of 8 and 7.  Hence removing one of largest two numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this.   I am thinking the vector x should be cast to numeric but this works.

```
x <- (c('7','2','3','8','8')) # read in data
remove <- tail(unique(x[order(x)]),2)  # take the unique elements and sort, identifying the last 2
x[ - c(which(x==remove[1])[1], which(x==remove[2])[1])  ] #remove only the one of each of the two found
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's a possibility with `match()`.

```
x[-match(tail(sort(unique(x)), 2), x)]
# [1] "2" "3" "8"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as the only option that extends to more than 2 removals.

Answer (score 6):

Another option using `which.max`

```
x[-c(which.max(x), match(max(x[x != max(x)]), x))]    
#[1] 2 3 8
```